# Use YouTube iframe API with Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, youtube-iframe-api

How do I construct a YT.Player object and access its properties `getCurrentTime()` within an Angular2 Component using Typescript?

I have tried installing several YouTube wrappers via npm, (eg: [youtube-player](https://github.com/gajus/youtube-player)), and added [Type definitions for YouTube](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/youtube/youtube.d.ts), with a reference in app.ts:

`/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/youtube/index.d.ts" />`

but I still get an error when importing, eg: `import YouTubePlayer from 'youtube-player';` returns `Cannot find module 'youtube-player'.`

I've forked the Angular2 [preboot/Webpack](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack) starter, my source repo is [here](https://github.com/edanweis/lifx-video-test)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 9):

You should not need any wrapper, including it yourself is not that much.

1.) include the youtube iFrame API via script tag.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const doc = (<any>window).document;
  let playerApiScript = doc.createElement('script');
  playerApiScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  playerApiScript.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
  doc.body.appendChild(playerApiScript);
}
```

2.) register your callback inside [onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements) function which the `Youtube API` will call when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    (<any>window).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
      this.player = new (<any>window).YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: 'YourVideoId',
        playerVars: {'autoplay': 1, 'rel': 0, 'controls': 2},
        events: {
          'onReady': () => {
          },
          'onStateChange': () => {
          }
        }
      });
    };
  }
```

You can also set `autoplay` to `0` so it does not play on load.

Now we have the `this.player` on the component level, and you can do other manipulations like:

- *pause*: `this.player.pauseVideo();`,
- *load other video* `this.player.loadVideoById('someOtherVideoId')` etc...

Answer (score 5):

> import YouTubePlayer from 'youtube-player'; returns Cannot find module 'youtube-player'

The library you are trying to use [`youtube-player`](https://github.com/gajus/youtube-player) is not the same as the library whole type definitions you are importing : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/youtube/youtube.d.ts (which is type type definition for the [official youtube library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/))

### Fix

You can create a declaration your self quite easily in a `vendor.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'youtube-player' {
 var foo:any;
 export = foo;
}
```

And you would in no way be worse off than using pure JavaScript.

## More

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html#

Comment: Thanks @basarat, I'm new to Typescript, and writing my own typescript definitions for a complex npm module seems quite difficult. Could you please provide a real example? or refer to an existing definition?

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem. Like basarat says, the youtube.d.ts typings definitions are not for the `youtube-player` package.

I followed basarat's advise and created a vendor.d.ts in my typings folder and added the definition (typings/vendor.d.ts):

```
declare module 'youtube-player' {
    var YouTubePlayer: any;
    export = YouTubePlayer;
}
```

The above was not sufficient to get it working though, I needed one further step. I used a different import statement to finally get it to work (MyController.ts):

```
import * as YouTubePlayer from 'youtube-player';

export class MyController {
    constructor() {
        let player = YouTubePlayer('playerid');
        player.loadVideoById('M7lc1UVf-VE');
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but got an error similar to 'TS2304 name 'YouTubePlayer' could not be found'. Do you have any ideas why it wouldn't work? I followed the exact same steps.

Answer (score 1):

Give https://github.com/orizens/ng2-youtube-player a try! Its written in ng2/ts and may support your needs.

Comment: Important: It's not free for commercial use!